# Proving every path is constant so that $X$ is not locally path connected

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is an uncountable set with the cocountable topology. I want to show two things:

- $X$ is locally connected
- Every path $\gamma : I \rightarrow X$ is constant

From this last bit I think it should be easy to show that $X$ is not locally path connected.

As a hint I got that I should look at $\gamma(I \cap \mathbb{Q})$ where $I \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is countable so it is closed.

Any help is appreciated!

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ I've boiled the first statement down to proving that each open in $X$ is connected. I tried to prove it as follows (rough sketch):
suppose $U$ is open but disconnected. Then there exist opens $V,W \subseteq X$ where the intersection with $U$ is non-empty and disjoint such that $U = V \cup W$. But since both $V$ and $W$ must have countable complement, they must be uncountable, but that means they must intersect!

I think this is the right approach but I can't seem to write down why this last bit holds (the fact that they must intersect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Each open subset of $X$ is connected:

X is uncountable and carries the cocountable topology.  This means that the open set are exactly the empty set and the complements of countable sets.

Observe that a nonempty countable set must have uncountable complement and hence cannot be open.

Now let $\emptyset \neq V\subseteq X$ be open. Its complement $X\setminus V$ is countable,  so every nonempty set $\emptyset \neq W\subseteq X\setminus V$ contained in its complement must also be countable, hence cannot be open.

In other words, given two nonempty *disjoint* sets $V,W\subseteq X$, at most one of them can be open.  So whenever you write an open set $U\subseteq X$ as $U=V\cup W$ for disjoint open sets $V,W\subseteq X$, at least one of $V,W$ must be empty.  Hence every open set $U\subseteq X$ must be connected.

### Any path $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ is constant:

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ be a continuous map.  Define $C:= [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} \subseteq [0,1]$. Since $C$ is countable, $\gamma(C)$ is countable.

Then $X\setminus \gamma(C)$ and thus $\gamma^{-1}(X\setminus \gamma(C))$ are open.  Since
$$\gamma^{-1}(X\setminus\gamma(C)) \subseteq [0,1] \setminus C,$$
by elementary set theory, the left set must be empty, otherwise there would be a non-empty open set in the complement of $C$ in $[0,1]$,  which would be a contradiction to the fact that the rationals (in $[0,1]$) are dense in $[0,1]$.

So indeed $\emptyset = \gamma^{-1}(X\setminus\gamma(C))$. This implies that $\gamma(C) = \gamma([0,1])$, again by elementary set theory.

It remains to show that $\gamma(C)$ contains only one point.

Suppose there are arbitrary disjoint sets $A,B\subseteq X$ such that $A\cup B = \gamma(C) = \gamma([0,1])$.  We want to show that one of $A,B$ is empty, then we are done.

Since $\gamma(C)$ is countable, $A$ and $B$ must be countable. Then they are closed.  Then in $$[0,1] = \gamma^{-1}(A) \cup \gamma^{-1}(B)$$  the two sets on the right are disjoint (elementary set theory) and closed.  Hence they are open (as each others complement).  Since $[0,1]$ is connected, $\gamma^{-1}(A)$ is empty or $\gamma^{-1}(B)$ is empty.  Since $A$ and $B$ are contained in $\gamma$'s image, this means that $A$ is empty, or $B$ is empty, respectively. QED

Answer (score 1):

First observation: Your proof has a tiny mistake. The fact that two sets are uncountable doesn't imply that they must intersect. I would rather explain that since they are disjoint, $V\subset X\setminus W$, so $V$ is countable. Since also $X\setminus V$ is countable, $X$ also is, a contradiction.

To solve the second part, we'll prove the following statements:

1. $\gamma$ has only countably many values.
2. $\gamma^{-1}(\{x\})$ is open and close, so it's either empty or equal to $X$.
3. Therefore $\gamma$ is constant.

**Proof**

1. Since $A:=I\cap \Bbb Q$ is countable, the set $B=\gamma(A)$ is also countable, so closed. Put $B=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$. From continuity we get that $C:=\gamma^{-1}(B)$ is closed. Because $A\subset C$ and $A$ is dense in $I$ and $C$ is closed, $C=I$.
2. Now fix $i\in\Bbb N$. Then
   $$\gamma^{-1}(B\setminus\{x_i\}) = \gamma^{-1}(B)\setminus\gamma^{-1}(\{x_i\}) = I\setminus\gamma^{-1}(\{x_i\})$$ is closed because $B\setminus\{x_i\}$ is countable hence closed. This shows that the sets $\gamma^{-1}(\{x_i\})$ are open and closed, which implies that $\gamma^{-1}(\{x_i\})=\emptyset$ or $\gamma^{-1}(\{x_i\})=I$ (connectedness of $I$).
3. Since $0\in\gamma^{-1}(\{\gamma(0)\})\neq \emptyset$, we get $\gamma^{-1}(\{\gamma(0)\})=I$. This shows that $\gamma$ is constant.